# T SQL Select tables based on values from another Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below select that retrieves all tables that begin with 'ABC_':

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name  LIKE 'ABC_%'
```

All of the 'ABC_' tables contain a field called 'SKU'.

I have another SELECT that retrieves a list of SKUs:

```
SELECT SKU from tblProducts
```

How do I return a list of 'ABC_' tables that contain at least one SKU from tblProducts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little dynamic SQL magic is all it takes:

Create a union all query with the tables you need, each of the inner queries with a `where exists` to make sure at least one row in them has a `sku` value that's also in the `tblproduct` table:

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @Sql = @Sql +N'UNION ALL SELECT '''+ table_name +N''' As TableName FROM '+ QUOTENAME(table_name) +
N' As P WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblProducts WHERE tblProducts.Sku = P.Sku) '
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name  LIKE 'ABC_%'

-- Remove the first "UNION ALL"
SELECT @Sql = STUFF(@Sql, 1, 10, '')

-- When dealing with Dynamic SQL, Print is your best friend
PRINT @Sql

-- Unremark once you check the printed SQL is what you wanted
--EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: I'd like to give you a +2 for `When dealing with Dynamic SQL, Print is your best friend`.

Comment: @Eric actually, that's inspired by something I've read right here on SO, can't remember who wrote the original and what the phrasing was exactly, but I liked the idea so much I've decided to add that to my regular answers arsenal. Hope that's not too much of a plagiarism - in case it is, keep in mind - "Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery".

Comment: I keep receiving the message 'Invalid column name 'SKU'.  This is definitely the column name though.

Comment: Well, I don't know what your tables look like - only you do. If you could edit your question to add some sample data as DDL+DML (create table and insert statements) of at least one ABC table and the product table that reproduces the problem then we will have something to work with.

Comment: @ZoharPeled my apolgies - one of the tables does not have the column 'SKU'.  I have excluded this and its working - thank you.

Comment: Glad to help :-)